# Django ORM instance methods vs property

Tags: django-orm

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods

I can't figure out the **motivation** due to which one might choose using an **instance method** over **property** or vice versa. Any ideas ?

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()

    def baby_boomer_status(self):
        "Returns the person's baby-boomer status."
        import datetime
        if self.birth_date < datetime.date(1945, 8, 1):
            return "Pre-boomer"
        elif self.birth_date < datetime.date(1965, 1, 1):
            return "Baby boomer"
        else:
            return "Post-boomer"

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        "Returns the person's full name."
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```